# Quill editor and AngularJS integration

Tags: angularjs, quill

I am trying to integrate Quill rich text editor in my angular project. When it displays the editor the toolbar icons are very very big. Please see the below image.

[image]

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Sanket Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the css files quill.core.css, quill.bubble.css and quill.snow.css
also add quill.min.js.

Comment: I put the snow.css and core.css in the angular.json style block and it started showing the editor. Thank you for your time and help.